# Extraneous newline on data copied from WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

With the default copy/paste behavior in the WPF DataGrid, it seems to place a newline after whatever is copied, whether it is the content of one cells or multiple rows.

Is there an easy way to make it not place that newline in the copied text?

I suppose I could do something like listening to Ctrl-C, executing the application.copy command, then replacing the data that was copied with a version that has the newline stripped off.  That seems awfully messy, though.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with the messy-seeming solution I described above.  It works, but it sure feels like there should be a better way of doing it.  Maybe in the future they'll add an event that hooks in at the right time to be able to edit the full clipboard contents directly before setting them.

```
    private RelayCommand _resultsGridCopyCommand;
    public RelayCommand ResultsGridCopyCommand {
        get {
            if (_resultsGridCopyCommand == null) {
                _resultsGridCopyCommand = new RelayCommand(this.CopyFromResultsGrid);
            }

            return _resultsGridCopyCommand;
        }
    }

    private void CopyFromResultsGrid(object grid) {
        var resultsGrid = (DataGrid)grid;
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, resultsGrid);

        var oldData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        var newData = new DataObject();

        foreach (var format in oldData.GetFormats()) {
            if (format.Equals("UnicodeText") || format.Equals("Text")) {
                newData.SetData(format, Regex.Replace(((String)oldData.GetData(format)), "\r\n$", ""));
            } else {
                newData.SetData(format, oldData.GetData(format));
            }
        }

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(newData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WPF `DataGrid` then handle its event called  `dataGrid.CopyingRowClipboardContent`

In the handler check if the

```
 if ((DataGridRow)sender.DataContext
        == dataGrid.SelectedItems.GetItemAt(dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count - 1))
 {
     var lastRowData = e.ClipboardRowContent;
     //// manipulate Clipboard to remove new line.
 }
```

I hope this guides you in correct direction.

Comment: This was pretty helpful in figuring out exactly what was going on, but I wasn't able to fix it here.  It turns out that the ClipboardRowContent contains a list of content items, and the newline is being added by the FormatClipboardCellValues on the event args, which I can't override there.
Unfortunately, the WPF team didn't see fit to include a DataCopied or similar event for editing the full contents generated to the clipboard.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the C# reflection APIs allow you to set properties and invoke methods, but not to set or override methods.

Comment: My bad will think on this later.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest solution instead of hooking up OS events and all that mess, is just remove empty line from the string that is going to be placed in the cell, just before Paste.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the question.  I want what is copied to the clipboard to not have the newline.  The data is going to be pasted into a separate textbox, or possibly external applications, so there's no way to strip the newline at that point without possibly doing the same to data that shouldn't have had it stripped off.